# how can i solve ConnectRestExtension error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

If i develop a ConnectRestExtension implementation and deploy a fat jar file excluding dependencies provided by Connect Framework in plugin.path, the following error occurs.

`org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements interface org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.ConnectRestExtension and which name matches~`

The full class name was written correctly in resource/META-INF/services/org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.ConnectRestExtension. Strangely, it works normally when deployed in the libs folder, which is the Kafka classpath. what could be the reason...
The following dependencies were used when developing the ConnectRestExtension implementation.

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <!-- connect api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jersey -->

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                    <encoding>${source-encoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Test coverage report-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!-- app build -->
        <profile>
            <id>app</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I have checked until the log is taken here.

```java
    private PluginScanResult scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(PluginSource source) {
        log.info("Loading plugin from: {}", source.location());
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Loading plugin urls: {}", Arrays.toString(source.urls()));
        }
        PluginScanResult plugins = scanPlugins(source);
        log.info("Registered loader: {}", source.loader());
        loadJdbcDrivers(source.loader());
        return plugins;
    }
```